# Davening at the Kotel

Tags: tefilla, kotel-western-wall

Is there a reason that praying at the Western Wall should have any more significance  (from a Halachic perspective or Hashkafa perspective) than davening in a shul anywhere else - whether it be in Yerushalayim  (whatever that may include ) or in Eretz Yisroel or even in Chutz La'aretz?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "significance". Do you mean efficacy as prayer or a more personal oomph? The Shechina never left the kotel so davening in the God's presence is good but that is not a quantifiable reason - Hashem is here, Hashem is there... http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=761

Comment: I'm not sure whether that ma'amar is referring to the Kosel that we go to. Furthermore, what would that mean anyway regarding tefilla? What if I daven in the Plaza before the wall? What if I daven on the steps going up to the Old City? What if I daven outside the City but I can see the Kosel? Sounds pretty strange to me. I'm not referring to "personal oomph" which has no shaychis to the Kosel. Someone can get ooomphs in many different ways and many different places.

Comment: [מכאן אתה למד שכל המתפלל במקום הזה בירושלם כאלו התפלל לפני כסא הכבוד ששער השמים שם הוא ופתח פתוח לשמוע תפלה שנ' וזה שער השמים.](http://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.35.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) - sounds like "significance" (for tefilla in particular) over at least the rest of Israel, and over chu"l. ("This place" refers to הר המוריה, see earlier in that section.) Not precisely the Kotel, but close, especially if you don't permit ascending to the Temple Mount.

Comment: @Rish But is there any advantage to "close"? Either you're in the "Har HaBayit" zone or the "Yerushalayim" zone.

Comment: @MarkA. Why dismiss "personal oomph"? There is a unique feeling and therefore unique kavanah one gets at the Kotel; isn't that enough?

Comment: The Kotel is the location which is physically closest to the Kodesh Kodashim outside of Har haBayit.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Not quite. You'd want to move quite a bit north along the retaining wall to be as close as you can. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Western_Wall

Comment: @DoubleAA Rav Shternbauch in Teshuvos veHanhagos (no, I don't know which siman right now) says based on sonar evidence that the space directly opposite the kotel plaza is likely the place of the mikdash and kodesh kedoshim (not like the Radbaz who wrote that the Even Shitiyah is under the dome) This is because we know the mikdash was built "kippin al gavei kippin" with tunnels underneath, because of impurity. Apparently only the space opposite the Kotel Plaza shows evidence of being hollow.

Comment: @NaftaliTzvi If you ignore all the other evidence then that might sound convincing to someone, but there's really no reason anymore to doubt the Radvaz if you look at all the available data. For once we should just let science and Mesorah agree and not go looking for problems...

Comment: Rav Shternbauch in Teshuvos Vehanhagos **Chelek 3 siman 39** suggests that the mikdash is likely directly opposite the Kotel Plaza. He sites  electromagnetic evidence (not sonar as I mistakenly wrote). Among archeologists this theory is called the Southern Location. R Shternbauch further cites Sefer Emek Hamelech intro. to chap. 9 quoting R Moshe Vital "its basis in the writings of the Arizl... the place of the temple is empty without building" Even if archeologist generally reject this view, R Shternbauch's acceptance (and apparently Arizals!) gives it heavy halachic/ hashkafik significance

Comment: @DoubleAA The maharsha makkos 24b chiddushei aggada Also implies that the place of the kodesh kedoshim is not under a building "this is why I  am laughing for it is destroyed and foxes walk in it and not the heathens... and this is what is written in Uriah 'because of you Zion will be a plowed field' meaning so no living creature will have satisfaction from it only a empty field and not planted only a plowed field not sprouting and Rabbi Akiva said now that I see that I see the prophecy of Uriah fulfilled  that foxes go in it and there is no heathen settlement... until the time of redemption

Comment: @naftal well it wasn't under a building when r Akiva was there. That's pretty universally accepted. Rav shternbuch or any rabbi having been convinced of any archaeological or scientific story doesn't have any halachic significance at all. It's upon everyone capable to determine the actual metziut. Then they can speak with Halakhic experts for how to apply halakha to it. And if I'm not mistaken the evidence you're trying to get at is temperature data based on infrared scans.

Comment: It should be noted though that the foundation rock could be immediately outside the dome of the rock, or somewhere else. The maharsha/ Rav Moshe Vital/ barren field idea therefore, does not necessitate the accepting the Southern  Location hypothesis. It does however conflict with the popular traditional identification (Radbaz) of Even Hashithiya with the Dome of the Rock

Comment: The Maharsha interprets the Biblical prophecy as saying the site will be barren **until the time of the redemption**. Uria's prophecy has halachic/hashkafic significance. See Rav Asher Weiss's tshuvot on techeilet where he describes archeological methodology as having no halachic significance (as 'umdena', lo zu darka shel torah! ect)

Comment: @Naf Sure Uria's prophecy does, but first of all, the Maharsha's interpretation of that Aggada is not a prophecy and the Maharsha himself never went to Israel to see what was actually going on so his claims are of dubious factual value. And second, it's not clear the current situation isn't considered barren. Have you been inside the dome of the rock? There's nothing there. It's a room with a barren rock. Archaeological methodology of course isn't itself of halakhic significance, but Metziut is of great halakhic significance according to everyone.

Comment: @DoubleAA See my new question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84627/do-rabbis-pasken-on-mitziyut

Answer (score 1):

Laolam lo zaza shechina mekotel hamaaravi! The Divine presence never left the Western wall! (See Midrash Tanhuma Exodus 10, Song of Songs 2:22, Exodus Raba 2:2, Zohar II:5b)

Comment: That wall isn't the Kotel, though. It's the western wall of the Temple. In any event, this is just your assertion currently. Please [edit] in a source to back up this claim about the Divine presence's movements.

Comment: Rabbi Avigdor Nebenzahl deduces that the midrashim indeed refer to the "kotel" wall of har habayit and not that of the Temple itself based on Rabbi  Eleazar HaKalir's _kinna _ Zechor Asher Ussu Tzar_ (16)  which reads in translation "... upon the entrance of Temple Mount he began to come, with the hand of commanders to destroy it. On the **western side** for a remembrance he left in it, and He stood behind our wall and did not fight its fight.

Comment: If the other three walls were knocked down and the western wall was left up as a remembrance, it's clearly not talking about the walls of Har Habayit since all four are still standing. This is obvious. The Kalir is referencing in that Kinah a Midrash (Eikha Rabba 1:31) that tells the story in full how three generals destroyed the three walls and the fourth general failed to destroy the western wall.

Comment: According to Chabad there are almost no ancient remains of the northern wall and only a bit of the eastern wall. i.e. they are in ruins. Regarding the southern wall, it is the _sharei chulda_ referred to in the midrash as also standing. Why did the Midrash Eicha omit them? I have no idea. Another explanation is that the southern wall does not border the sacred Temple Mount area, and therefore doesn't count

Comment: Huh??? If those walls weren't there, the dirt inside would flow out. That's what a retaining wall does. It retains the dirt. Clearly all four walls are fully standing! You can even go walk around and see them all. There's no need for us to argue about a Metziut that anyone can go see.

Comment: Which Tanchuma is this, Yelamdeinu or Buber ?