# Do Rabbis pasken on mitziyut

Tags: halacha-theory

If a Rabbi rules halacha based on his understanding of scientific of archeological mitziut,  does the ruling have halachic standing for someone who has a different understanding?

Comment: Obviously, if the rabbi's understanding of the facts is mistaken his ruling can't be binding. That leads to all sorts of crazy situations depending how badly he misunderstood the facts (eg. rabbi ruled a marriage is nullified because he mistakenly thought the spouses were siblings)