# Source for kedushah of the kotel?

Tags: sources-mekorot, kotel-western-wall

I’ve heard before that the kedushah of the beis hamikdash went into the kosel when it was destroyed, anyone know of a source? Any other sources of the kedushah/value of the kosel in general?

Comment: http://www.adathisraelshul.org/e-torah/parsha/28-bamidbar/36-bamidbar-5774-touching-the-wall

Comment: הר הבית יש לו קדושה עין תחילת מסכת כלים

Comment: I don't know of any holiness of the kosel. It's a wall. An old wall. The plaza in front of it has the sanctity of a shul nowadays. A popular shul I'd even say

Comment: If you find any sources about the Kotel's value in the last 60 years they're probably just trying to distract you from the mountain behind it, whether for political reasons, fear of people going up in the wrong places, or something else. It's just a thinly veiled fad.

Comment: Duplicate? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75596/davening-at-the-kotel