Does the kotel (western wall) have the Kavod of a synagogue
According to Halacha, does the kotel (western wall) have the Kavod of a synagogue? The reason I ask is because it is sort of a designated area for prayer but does this have halachic implications regarding its sanctity (like there are certain prohibitions in a synagogue/beit haknesset)?

Are you asking about the kotel or the kotel plaza? The kotel itself is just a wall next to the plaza that isn't used for anything. The plaza area is where people pray

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75596/davening-at-the-kotel

R. Mordekhai Gross writes that it does indeed have the sanctity of a synagogue (Menuhath Emeth p. 383):

השטח שמחוץ לכותל המערבי אינו הר הבית ולא נוהג בו קדושת הר הבית לפי דעת
רוב הפוסקים. ולפיכך מותרת הגישה לכותל המערבי ללא טבילה במעיין או
במקוה. ורשאי אדם לנעול נעליים בגשתו לכותל המערבי, אף שאסור לאדם להכנס
להר הבית בנעליים שעל רגליו אמנם רבים מהדרים לטבול במקוה טרם גשתם לכותל
המערבי. ולפנים היו צדיקים שאף חלצו נעליהם בבואם אל הקודש ליד הכותל
המערבי וכך נהג ק"ז הרה"ק רבי אלעזר מנדיל מלעלוב ירושלים והרה"ק בעל
מנחת אלעזר.
ומכל מקום קדושת בית הכנסת קיימת ליד כותל המערבי ונוהג שם כל דיני
וקדושת בית הכנסת ואף רחבת הכותל שאינה מקורה יש עליה קדושת בית הכנסת
ואין לה דין בקעה שאין מתפללים בה [עי' שו"ע או"ח סי' צ ס"ה] כיון שהיא
מוקפת במחיצות ובניינים.
כל השטח המיועד לתפילת הציבור דינו כבית הכנסת ואף השטח הגדול שלפני רחבת
הכותל המערבי שמתפללים בו בציבור רק באירועים בעת שמתכנסים המונים מבני
ישראל נוהג בו קדושת בית הכנסת.
The area outside the Western Wall is not the Temple Mount, nor does it
have the sanctity of the Temple Mount, according to the opinion of
most decisors. Therefore, access to the Western Wall is permitted
without immersion in a spring or in a miqwah. And a person may wear
shoes when approaching the Western Wall, the removal of which is only
necessary when visiting the Temple Mount, nevertheless many immerse in
a miqwah before visiting the Western Wall. And in prior times there
were righteous people who would remove their shoes when coming near
the sanctity [that exists] next to the Western Wall, and such was the
practice of R. El’azar Mendel of Lelów and the Minhath El’azar.
In any event, the sanctity of the synagogue exists next to the Western
Wall and all the laws and sanctity of the synagogue are practiced
there, and even the plaza of the Wall which is not covered has the
sanctity of a synagogue, and it does not have the law of a valley
wherein one should not pray [SA OH 90:5] since it is surrounded by
partitions and buildings.
The entire area designated for communal public prayer its law is as a
synagogue, and even the large area in front of the Western Wall plaza
where public prayers are held only on occasions when large crowds of
Jews gather has the sanctity of the synagogue.

See inside for a continuation on the proper conduct befitting its sanctity.

Like @DoubleAA asserts the plaza is where people daven.
It can be argued that this does have the sanctity of a shul. Refer to the Yerushalmi Megilla which writes:

עַד כְּדוֹן בְּשֶׁבְּנָייָהּ לְשֶׁם בֵּית הַכְּנֶסֶת. בְּנָייָהּ לְשֵׁם חָצֵר וְהִקְדִּישָׁהּ מָהוּ. נִיִשְׁמְעִינָהּ מִן הָדָא. קוֹנָם לְבַיִת זֶה שֶׁאֵינִי נִכְנָס. וְנַעֲשָׂה בֵית הַכְּנֶסֶת. הָדָא אָֽמְרָה. בְּנָייָהּ לְשֵׁם חָצֵר וְהִקְדִּישָׂהּ קָֽדְשָׁה. אֵימָתַי קָֽדְשָׁה. מִיַּד [אוֹ] בִּשְׁעַת הַתִּשְׁמִישׁ. נִישְׁמְעִינָהּ מִן הָדָא. הָעוֹשֶׂה תֵיבָה לְשֵׁם סֵפֶר וּמִטְפָּחוֹת לְשֵׁם סֵפֶר. עַד שֶׁלֹּא נִשְׁתַּמֵּשׁ בָּהֶן הַסֵּפֶר מוּתָּר לְהִשְׁתַּמֵּשׁ בָּהֶן הֶדְיוֹט. מִשֶׁנִּשְׁתַּמֵּשׁ בָּהֶן הַסֵּפֶר אָסוּר לְהִשְׁתַּמֵּשׁ בָּהֶן הֶדְיוֹט. [ומַּה] אִם אֵילּוּ שֶׁנַּעֲשׂוּ לְשֵׁם סֵפֶר אֵינָן קְדֵישׁוֹת אֶלָּא בִשְׁעַת הַתַּשְׁמִישׁ. זוֹ שֵׁבְּנָייָהּ לְשֵׁם חָצֵר לֹא כָל־שֶׁכֵּן. אֵילּוּ שֶׁעָשָׂאָן לְשֵׁם חוּלִין וְהִקְדִּישָׁן מָה הֵן. כְּמַה דְאַתְּ אֲמַר תַּמָּן. בְּנָייָהּ לְשֵׁם חָצֵר וְהִקְדִּישָׁהּ קָֽדְשָׁה. וְהָכָא עָשָׂאָם לְשֵׁם חוּלִין וְהִקְדִּישָׁן קָדַשׁ
So far if it was built as a synagogue. If it was built as a courtyard and he dedicated it, what is the rule? Let us hear from the following: “A Konam (a confirmation of a vow) that I shall not enter this house and it was turned into a synagogue.” This implies that if it was built as a courtyard and he dedicated it, it became sanctified. When is it sanctified, immediately [or] at the moment of use? Let us hear from the following: If one builds a chest for a scroll or makes ribands for a scroll. As long as it was not used for a scroll, profane use is permitted; after it was used for the scroll, private use is prohibited. Therefore, if these who were made for a scroll are not sanctified until used, this which was built as courtyard is it not more so? What is the rule for these if they were made for profane use? Since you are saying there, if it was built as a courtyard and he dedicated it, it is sanctified, so here if they were made for profane use and he dedicated them they are sanctified.

In other words, the courtyard area takes on the holiness of a shul.
